# open div with the help of javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to open div when i take my mouse cursor on some specific link, and hide that div when i mouesout from the link.

Comment: By open do you mean display it on hover? implying that it is meant to be hidden by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function show(divID) {
var item = document.getElementById(divID);
if (item) {
item.className='unhidden';
}
}
function hide(divID) {
var item = document.getElementById(divID);
if (item) {
item.className='hidden';
}
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.hidden {
display: none;
}

.unhidden {
display: block;
}
</style>

<p><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="show('test1');" onmouseout="hide('test1')">Show/Hide</a></p>

<div id="test1" class="hidden">
testing
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Old school:

```
<a href="#" id="foo" onmouseover="togglediv();" onmouseout="togglediv();">Toggler</a>
<div id="bar">Content</div>
```

And the js:

```
togglediv = function() {
  var mydiv = document.getElementById('bar');
  mydiv.style.display = mydiv.style.display == '' ? 'block' : '';
}
```

If you don't want to lard up your HTML with inline event handlers (and you shouldn't), you can go with something like this:

```
function setupHover(id){
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el.addEventListener) { // modern browsers
    el.addEventListener ('mouseover',togglediv,false);
    el.addEventListener ('mouseout',togglediv,false);
  } else if (el.attachEvent) { // IE
    el.attachEvent ('onmouseover',togglediv);
    el.attachEvent ('onmouseout',togglediv);
  } else { // anybody else
    el.onmouseover = togglediv;
    el.onmouseout = togglediv;
}
```

@idealmachine shows a nice way to encapsulate this in a listener function in his(?) answer.

Then you'd call `setupHover('foo')` in your `onload`:

```
window.onload = function(){
  setupHover('foo');
  // other stuff
};
```

Even easier, if you're using a library (jQuery, for example), you can do this while transparently abstracting away cross-browser differences:

```
$(document).ready( function(){ // when the DOM is loaded
  $('a#foo').hover( // listen for hovers on the <a>
    function(){ 
      $('#bar').toggle(); // and toggle visiblity directly
      // $('#bar').toggleClass('visible'); // or toggle a class to achieve same
    } 
  );
});
```

That's probably easiest, although you do need to include jQuery or your equivalent library of choice.

All assume your div is initially hidden:

```
<style type="text/css">
div#yourdiv { display: none; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that does not use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). jQuery makes this possible in many fewer lines of code. Just read the documentation of methods like [`.show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and you will easily see why.

The code below uses JavaScript's [ability to set dynamic CSS styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style). It also attaches event handlers entirely within JavaScript to remain as unobtrusive as possible in the HTML. Here's a [live link to my example](http://jsfiddle.net/D4JKX/1/) so that you can see if this is what you want or not.

HTML:

```
<a id="myMagicLink" href="http://www.google.com/">My Magic Link</a>
<div id="openingDiv">Opens a div</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
#openingDiv {
    background-color: #ffc;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function listenForEvent(elem, eventType, handler) {
    if(elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(eventType, handler, false);
    }
    else {
        elem.attachEvent('on' + eventType, handler);
    }
}

listenForEvent(window, 'load', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('myMagicLink'),
        div = document.getElementById('openingDiv');

    listenForEvent(link, 'mouseover', function() {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    });

    listenForEvent(link, 'mouseout', function() {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    });

});
```